# Represnt List of list to string with a deliminator

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to write my custom `toString` to convert a list of lists to a string with delimiter `|`

```
trait Msg {   
  def toCustString(): String
}

trait Ele[T] extends Msg {   
    val value: T    
    override def toCustString(): String = s"${value}"        
}

trait Grp extends Msg {    
  val list: Seq[Msg]
  override def toCustString(): String = ""
}


case class TypeA(value: Int) extends Ele[Int]
case class TypeB(value: String) extends Ele[String]
case class TypeC(value: Float) extends Ele[Float]
case class MyGrp(list: Seq[Msg]) extends Grp

object Demo extends App {
  val grp1 = MyGrp(Seq(TypeA(2)))
  val grp2 = MyGrp(Seq(TypeB("ABC"), TypeC(20)))
  val s=MyGrp(Seq(grp1,grp2))
  print(s)
}
```

Final output should be `2|ABC|20|`.Please notice the deliminator at end

Can anyone suggest a solution how to work on the above nested structure?

I have tried the below

```
  override def toCustString(): String = list.map(_.toCustString()).toString
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? I see an empty `toCustomString` implementation...

Comment: I tried `s.productIterator.mkString("|")`

Comment: `print(s)` is going to call the `.toString` method. Which do you want, the `print(s.toCustString)` solution or the `print(s)` solution?

Comment: print(s.toCustString) one .I am trying to use `foldLeft`

Comment: `foldLeft`? What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @jwvh foldleft to create a string accumulator and then use accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to turn everything in the `list` to its `CustString` representation before calling `mkString()` on it.

```
trait Msg {
  def toCustString: String
}

trait Ele[T] extends Msg {
  val value: T
  override def toCustString: String = value + "|"
}

trait Grp extends Msg {
  val list: Seq[Msg]
  override def toCustString: String =
    list.map(_.toCustString).mkString
}
```

Tested as follows.

```
case class TypeA(value: Int) extends Ele[Int]
case class TypeB(value: String) extends Ele[String]
case class TypeC(value: Float) extends Ele[Float]
case class MyGrp (list:Seq[Msg]) extends Grp

val grp1 = MyGrp(Seq(TypeA(2)))
val grp2 = MyGrp(Seq(TypeB("ABC"), TypeC(20)))
val s=MyGrp(Seq(grp1,grp2))
println(s.toCustString)   // "2|ABC|20.0|"
```

Comment: Yes but I want  "2|ABC|20.0|".Notice the deliminator at end

Comment: @coder25 `println(s)` calls the `toString` method to get a string representation of an instance. Your method is called `toCustString` so you must explicitly use `println(s.toCustString)`. This does work

Comment: Can you suggest a way to use `foldleft` for this

Comment: @coder25; Simple fix. Have a look. No `foldLeft` needed.

Comment: thks but in actual use case it is something different let me edit the question